# How to open a remote resource with fsockopen and allow_url_fopen disabled, no socket (extension) support, and no cURL support?

Tags: php, connection

In a PHP application I wrote, I have to access a remote resource (i.e. URL) in all possible situations/server configurations. For that I have to consider any combination of configuration options.

So my question is: how to open a remote resource with `fsockopen` and `allow_url_fopen` disabled, no socket (extension) support, and no cURL support?

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this is possible?

Comment: Socket support is required

Comment: @NathanRobb No, I just am hopping very much.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois By what?

Comment: `fsockopen`, it opens a socket, therefore socket support is required.

Comment: @7heo.tk Sorry, it does not seem that this is possible. I apologize, but why don't you have socket support if you're trying to use sockets?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I am talking about the [socket extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php). Of course PHP knows how to handle C sockets; but the `fsockopen` function is disabled in `php.ini`, it seems.

Comment: Oh, interpretated your question differently. Well, you're basically trapped if you don't have access to the system. There is no other way.

Comment: @NathanRobb I am trying to open a remote file, but I think that the server setup is too secure for me to be able to do that. I opened this question because I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Dang. I was afraid of this. Thank you for your answer; I'll wait a little to close the question in case we're all missing something.

Comment: @7heo.tk You may need to see if you can get the server opened up a little bit for you then. To clarify, you mean that the host machine for your code is too secure, not the remote host?

Comment: @NathanRobb I mean that the server configuration (that runs my code) is too tight for me to be able to access any remote file.

Comment: @7heo.tk Ok, that's what I thought, just needed clarification :) Yes, unfortunately it looks like what you are looking for is not possible. However, if you aren't hard-fast on fsockopen and cURL, maybe you can look into FTP through PHP to access your remote file? I'm no expert with this, but you may be able to start here http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php   If you can get your remote server to run an FTP instance, you may be able to download the file directly to your host.

Comment: @7heo.tk Also, this is a long-shot as I don't know exactly how your server is set up, but you may be able to use `fopen()` on the remote file as well. `fopen()` and `fsockopen()` do different things and if you're just trying to get the file, `fopen()` may be all you need. I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: @NathanRobb AFAIK, `fopen()` does require `allow_url_fopen` to be set to `1` (AKA to be enabled). I'll try asking for `allow_url_fopen` to be changed or I'll go the FTP route, I guess. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @7heo.tk Any time, wish I could be more help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to open a remote resource via HTTP with the following conditions:

- `fsockopen` disabled
- `allow_url_fopen` disabled
- no support for the `socket` extension
- no support for the `cURL` extension

The solution is either to provide the files via other means (FTP (via PHP or manually), etc) or to require the server administrator to relax the security (for example to remove `fsockopen` from the disabled functions list.